# Typing with built-in map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

My IDE (PyCharm) is failing to auto-complete the following:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def listify(x: T) -> List[T]:
    return [x]

str_list: List[str] = ['a', 'b']
listified = map(listify, str_list)
listified[0].<TAB>  # autocomplete fail, IDE fails to recognize this is a List
```

Is this a problem with my IDE, or is `typing` not compatible with `map`?

Whatever the answer, I tried to fix by wrapping `map`:

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable, List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
U = TypeVar('U')

def listify(x: T) -> List[T]:
    return [x]

def univariate_map(func: Callable[[T], U], x: Iterable[T]) -> Iterable[U]:
    return map(func, x)  

str_list: List[str] = ['a', 'b']
listified = univariate_map(listify, str_list)
listified[0].<TAB>  # still fails to autocomplete
```

Again, is this a problem with my IDE, or are my expectations of the `typing` module incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `map` returns an iterator and you can't index (`[0]`) iterators. When you cast the `map` to a `list` then PyCharm recognizes the type:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def listify(x: T) -> List[T]:
    return [x]

str_list: List[str] = ['a', 'b']
listified = list(map(listify, str_list))  # list is new here
listified[0].
```

Screenshot:

[image]

However, it seems like PyCharm can deduce the type for your function even without any type hints (in this case).

Comment: Oops, that was silly. Sorry, I should have tried running some actual code instead of just trying to autocomplete. Thanks!

Comment: @abccd ok! You really confused me there :)